# What electric field strength in the range 50MHz to 3.5GHz should be considered "natural"?

Tags: emf

If we were to measure the electric field strength of the earth's surface in the range 50MHz to 3.5GHz (in the absence of any man-made transmitter), what value should be considered "natural"?

The next paragraph was in the original formulation of the question, but it is useless and is left here only to make sense of the comments: [I read](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Natural_electric_field_of_the_Earth) that the electric field should be about 150 Volts per meter, but I do not understand what range this refers to.  (Or maybe I do not understand what electric fields are.)  I measured it in the above range (with a Tenmars 195) and I got much smaller values.

Comment: 150V/m is a very high field strength, this would be the level you might see very close to a powerful transmitter. Where did you get the figure of 150V/m for the background level?

Comment: It is in the Wikipedia article I linked in my question.  Click on "I read".  It also looks quite high to me, that's why I thought the frequency range could be an issue (but I am quite ignorant in the matter...)

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking at static field strengths? The FCC limits for radiated emissions range from 90 to 300 micro-volts per meter over 30-1000 MHz. Natural levels would be far below those limits (otherwise there would be no point in having the limits).

Comment: I have just had a quick look and cannot see anything about 50MHz to 3.5GHz

Comment: Yes. The 150 V/m figure is for the static electric field. Not in the range of 50-3500 MHz.

Comment: DC field is different, this may well be the case, but you will not measure that with RF measurement equipment

Comment: "The static fair-weather electric field ... drops exponentially with height to under 1 V/m at 30 km altitude."

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  So, back to my question, what is a natural value in the range 50 MHz to 3.5 GHz.  @mkeith says natural levels would be "far below" 90 to 300 micro-volts per meter.  How far exactly?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you wish to know this? It is possible that the noise of your measurement system will be larger than the natural background. In fact, I believe that will be the case.

Comment: @mkeith: I would like to understand how the presence of cell towers and radio/tv broadcast affects my environment.  I am unable to get useful (to me) data from what I can read online, so I wanted to make some measurement myself.  I understand that the range I specify is the range for FM/TV/Cell broadcast (though not AM), so I want to make measurements in that range.  I have a TENMARS TM-195.  I have started making some measurements in my area and I am getting between 1 and 2 volts/m, which looks higher than the FCC guidelines.  I'd appreciate any help.  I don't know much about the subject.

Comment: The FCC guidelines I mentioned are for devices which do not intentionally radiate. They are not safety limits. The purpose of those guidelines is to make sure the devices do not interfere with reception of radio transmissions. So it makes sense that the guidelines would be set lower than the signals you are receiving from transmission sources. If you didn't already, you should calculate the noise floor due to Earth's black body radiation. Compare that with the noise floor of your equipment. In any event, you will not be able to detect signals below the noise floor.

Answer (score 2):

Black body radiation may be the thing you are looking for: -

[image]

The graph above covers above visible light wavelengths down to wavelengths of 100 um (3,000 GHz). The formula is called Planck's equation: -

[image]

where B is the spectral radiance, T is the absolute temperature of the black body, kB is the Boltzmann constant, h is the Planck constant, and c is the speed of light.

This also applies to more mundane frequencies but of course the powers are (thankfully) much smaller. The earth is the "black body" and you can assume it to be largely at 273 kelvin.

You could use [**this**](https://www.sensiac.org/external/resources/calculators/infrared_radiance_calculator.jsf) calculator to get the emissive power at any wavelength. Or maybe just make a spreadsheet but the great thing about the caluculator above is that it calculates the total emission across a given bandwidth (that you enter).

You then need to convert it to watts per square metre in order to determine the E and H field quantities because, E and H multiplied together produce watts per square metre.

As per normal radio waves, E is 377 (120\$\pi\$) times bigger than H because 377 ohms is the impedance of free space.

Finally, if you are going to check this value with an antenna and some very sensitive electronics cooled down substantially you will need to take into account the antenna's aperture (defined in square metres).

[**Further reading**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiSmsCz0srKAhUFUBQKHYNoBSkQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.stanford.edu%2Fclass%2Fee252%2Fhandouts%2Fantenna_noise.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGRd7lkaK0DjpmMvuHsvn-7v2MLxA&sig2=FdGbs3q24s-yYaw1uSYc3g&cad=rja) on black body radiation related to antenna theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful pointers.  But just to make it a complete answer, what would be the final number?  (Chances are that if I try I am going to overlook something.)

Comment: Ah, now that would be too easy for you. You can probably google that number somewhere. I'm interested only in explaining why.

Comment: @Manu did you use the calculator (in my answer) and get an answer to this?

Comment: This looks like a better calculator: https://www.spectralcalc.com/blackbody_calculator/blackbody.php